# Is GaoGao-chan based/inspired on Stitch?

Tags: pocos-udon-world

*Poco's Udon World* has a "spin-off" in-universe children series *Gao-Gao and the Blue Sky*, in which a super-dangerous alien bent on conquest and destruction comes to Earth to destroy/conquer it and then befriends two human girls and ends up as its defender.

One cannot avoid noticing the similarities with Disney's Stitch character.

Is there any connection?

Comment: I've heard the Stitch character is pretty popular in Japan, so it's plausible there's a connection, though I've no idea if there is one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stitch!

Comment: @Torisuda did you mean [Stitch!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stitch_%28Lilo_%26_Stitch%29#Stitch.21_.28anime.29) ????

Comment: Yes. Weird, I was on the correct page and copied the link from the navigation bar. Anyway, seems you understood what I meant.